# How can I manage the download location, by file types, in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download, google-chrome-extensions

Although this is partly a question about Chrome (where the problem is), this is more about the extensions (where I hope to find a solution).

I recall a plugin for FireFox that would take a given file type (i.e. .jpg) and push it to a [.jpg download] folder, instead of downloading it to the default [download] folder. I know how to change the default [download] folder; I am looking for a less heavy-handed approach. I would prefer answers that reference Chrome extensions, rather than some kind of background application that has the same functionality.

- Is there a similar plugin that will migrate specific file types to user-determined folders, rather than the default download folder?

Comment: I was also looking for this extension, but didn't find yet. Sure, you can use the highly-configurable download manager for that, but normally they're coming with some junk/ads onboard, so I'm just avoiding them.

Comment: Search for Chrome extensions, including RegExp Download Organizer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently put together a Chrome extension called [Downloads Router](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloads-router/fgkboeogiiklpklnjgdiaghaiehcknjo) that does exactly this -- based on MIME type rather than file extension, though. It also allows for routing based on source domain (e.g. files from iconfinder.com goes to images/icons/ instead of images/).

Comment: Looking forward to expanded Linux coverage. Being able to add pathing options to a my SDB (secondary hard drive) would be rad. I wlll be sure to provide some feedback and appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @mfg Thanks for the input! Absolute paths on Linux and a nicer, dialog-style path selector are right at the top of the todo-list. :) Feel free to add any and all bugfix/feature requests to the issues tracker on Bitbucket.

Comment: @mfg Hi again. Seems I managed to overlook this text on the chrome.downloads API page: "A file path relative to the Downloads directory to contain the downloaded file, possibly containing subdirectories. Absolute paths, empty paths, and paths containing back-references ".." will cause an error." Interesting that it works with absolute paths on Win/OSX... I noticed that symlinks work, though, so that should do the trick for you for the moment!

Answer (score 5):

The Firefox plugin is called [Automatic Save Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/automatic-save-folder/). For Chrome there is not yet a similar tool, the closest thing is [Belvedere Automated file manager](https://github.com/adampash/belvedere). [Here](http://hasi-journal.blogspot.com/2010/05/belvedere-automated-file-manager.html) is a little more info on how to use the tool.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome extension
[Download Location Controller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-location-control/ffblgjnocedmidbaeignfilgnhikfdbc)
is described as:

> Saves files in folders by their extensions.

(I haven't tried it, so cannot comment on it, but its reviews are very positive.)

Another useful extension is the open-source
[Organize Downloads by Date](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/organize-downloads-by-dat/ipjljbilkibpncgnagphiamkkdilbbki?hl=en),
described as:

> Organizes your download folder by date. Example: YEAR/MONTH/FILE
>
> This extension automatically organizes your downloads by date, like
> so:
>
> Before: Downloads/example.file
> After: Downloads/2018/10/example.file

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ultimate solution what you want.
**Download by extension**
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-by-extension/ogflhjilpmfeejjdnelhakfokcldpfki/related

Enjoy!!